# Get query id from an given query in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am working on a simple registration database.I have seen a lot posts about how to get something if you know id, but i need it backwards. I need to get the id of the query, that i define with some conditions.

Here's my code:

There is  a simple database init:

```
class User(Base):
__tablename__ = "user_table"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(20))
    password: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(20))
```

Here is a query with some conditions that i want:

```
id_query = session.query(User).filter(User.name=="John")
```

So for example i am having this database:

| id | name | password |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | James | blabla123 |
| 2 | John | bloblo234 |

I am thinking about something like this:

```
user_id = id_query.id
# i expect user_id = 2
```

But i get this error:

`AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'id'`

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to fetch a row: `id_query.one().id`